# Gaussian with poles (complex contour integration)

Tags: integration, gaussian

I am considering the integral

$$ I = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \text{d} x \: \frac{f(x)}{x}e^{-x^2}, $$

where $f(x)$ is an even function of $x$ with no singularities/poles. Due to the (anti)symmetry of the integral, I am pretty sure that the Cauchy principal value of this integral is zero. However, I would like to prove this via contour integration. As such, I consider a related integral:

$$ J = \oint_{C} \text{d}z \: \frac{f(z)}{z}e^{-z^2}$$

where for some closed contour $C$. However, I am having trouble choosing the contour. One cannot adopt a semicircle in the upper half-plane (enclosing the pole) as the integral over the portion of the semicircle for $\theta \in [\pi/2,\pi]$ will not vanish by Jordan's Lemma. I thought that one could adopt a rectangular contour in the upper half-plane (once again enclosing the pole), running from $-R$ to $R$ along the real axis (going below the pole at $z=0$), and then from $-R$ to $R$ along $z=+ia$ for some positive real number $a$. However, I come unstuck when trying to manipulate the integral along the upper part of the rectangle.

Is my choice of contour appropriate for finding the Cauchy principle value of $I$, or is there a more appropriate contour? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what about $\{\varepsilon e^{i\theta }\mid \theta \in [-\pi,0]\}\cup[-\varepsilon ,R]\cup\{Re^{i\theta }\mid \theta \in [0,\pi]\}\cup[-R,-\varepsilon ]$ ?

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Surb! However, doesn't the Gaussian part diverge for $R \rightarrow \infty$ for $\theta \in [\pi/2,\pi]$? Because $\cos 2\theta$ changes sign across $\theta = \pi/2$, so that part of the contour won't vanish due to Jordan's Lemma?

Comment: I don't know what is Jordan lemma. My previous comment was just a suggestion and may not work.

Comment: With residues I get $J=2\pi i f(0)$

Comment: @Raffaele, do you mean $J = 2\pi i f(0)$? I pretty confident that $I =0$, but I agree that $J = 2\pi i f(0)$.

Comment: @PhysyCola under the hypothesis that $f(x)$ has no poles/singularities  $I$ doesn't converge

Comment: In order to apply Cauchy's Integral Theorem, $f$ needs to be analytic in and on the contour $C$.  Is it?  Note that even the function $f(z)=|z|$ has no pole or other singularity.  But it fails to be analytic.

Comment: @Raffaele, surely it converges in the Cauchy Principle value sense of the integral? Indeed, you can relate it to $E_1(z)$, and show that it must be zero.

Comment: @MarkViola, the condition for applying Cauchy's residue theorem is for the function to be holomorphic, or have I missed something?

Comment: I stated $f(z)$ needs to be analytic.  What do you not understand?

Comment: @MarkViola, apologies, I mis-understood; I thought you were using $f(z)$ to refer to the entire integrand, rather than what I have defined as $f(z)$. In my integral, $f(z)$ is indeed analytic. Specifically, 

$$ f(z) = \sum_{m=0}^\infty a_m H_m(x) $$

where $H_m$ is the $m$-th Hermite polynomial.